# How to programmatically set access for a google worksheet created through worksheet api?

Tags: google-api, permissions, google-sheets-api

I am having an issue using the google worksheet api. Basically I have a service account setup that can retrieve files etc from my google drive account. This works fine. I can get a worksheet and read the data.

Next I create a new worksheet and it creates fine. I checked the response url and found the new worksheets url. However when I try access the new worksheet through the browser I get a not authorized error. Does anyone out there know how I would set permissions on a new worksheet on create?

I can't see anything in the docs for a param or something like it that would set these.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#create

Comment: Add as editor via Drive REST API. The Sheets API is for manipulating the data and formatting of sheets, not controlling access to them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37968249/9337071 for the answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google sheets API v4 Create sheet and invite users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967937/google-sheets-api-v4-create-sheet-and-invite-users)